# sanitize upper vs lower case

Tags: javascript, theory, sanitization

Is there a reason that when sanitizing a string, the characters are converted to `lowercase` as opposed to `uppercase`?

I've see this convention in many languages, but in terms of my current environment, we'll say `Rails` and/or `Javascript`

Comment: Sanitizing to what? HTML?

Comment: That depends entirely on *how* you are sanitising, and is up to you. Show us your code.

Comment: I don't really have any code perse, it's just a convention that I've noticed in various sanitization methods; which is they all seem to convert user input to lowercase as part of the sanitization. Basically, I'm wondering if there is any specific advantage to converting to lowercase vs converting to uppercase.

Comment: @greetification: A counterexample would be HTML tag names. They are sanitised uppercase in the DOM. No, there is no advantage, except maybe readability and aversion against shouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No specific reason to my knowledge, but neither uppercasing nor lowercasing is the whole story in the Unicode world.

For example, the German letter `ß` is exactly equivalent to `ss`; they're both lowercase, and a word spelled with `ß` can also be spelled with `ss`.

Conversely, in Turkish, `ı` (dotless i) is distinct from `i` (dotted i), but unless your locale is Turkish, uppercasing either one produces `I` (dotless ASCII I). This changes meaning too. You don't want to use the wrong one; they aren't equivalent.

Because of this, some programming languages offer more specific "case normalizing" conversions per the case folding rules in section 3.13 of the Unicode standard; Python 3.3 introduced [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) for that reason. It's much like `.lower()`, but will also normalize stuff like `ß` to `ss` because they're logically equivalent (if you're uniquifying, you wouldn't want to treat two strings that differ only in `ß` vs. `ss` to be treated as different).

If you don't have case folding available in your language, then the distinction between normalizing as upper vs. lower case is mostly by convention.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has toLowerCase() as well as toUpperCase().  You can use either!

I think the answer to your question though really stems from unix systems deciding many decades ago to use case sensitivity and having all lower case commands.  This translated to case sensitive urls in Apache, and to be cross O/S compatible, we just made sure everything was always lowercase.

I guess all upper case could be and is used at times, but it's also obnoxious :)